# Focus existing terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` shortcut

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, window

I tend to use the terminal a lot,

So I wondering if there is a way I can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> focus the existing terminal if there is one, otherwise create a new terminal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a small script which will raise the GNOME Terminal:

```
echo 'xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class gnome-terminal)'> ~/raiseterminal.sh && chmod +x ~/raiseterminal.sh
```

or if you want to check if Terminal is already running, use:

```
echo -e $'if ps aux | grep "[g]nome-terminal" > /dev/null\n then xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class gnome-terminal)\n else gnome-terminal &\nfi' > ~/raiseterminal.sh && chmod +x ~/raiseterminal.sh
```

This will create the script ~/raiseterminal.sh with this content:

```
if ps aux | grep "[g]nome-terminal" > /dev/null                                                                                                                                                                                
 then xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class gnome-terminal)                                                                                                                                            
 else gnome-terminal&                                                                                                                                                                                                          
fi
```

Open the preferences to set up a [custom keyboard shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) and set the command to `/home/$USER/raiseterminal.sh`, but make sure to change *$USER* to your actual username.

If you only want to raise the terminal on a specific screen or desktop, see `xdotool search --help` for more information on how to do this.

There are also various [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000050/how-to-programmatically-switch-to-a-specific-window-in-compiz) which work better with other window managers.

Comment: You could add a `| head -n1` after searching gnome-terminal windows to prevent an error if more than one windows are found

Answer (score 9):

why don't you try `tilda` or `guake`, both available in ubuntu repositories. Although they don't specifically do what you're after, I'm sure they are that thing that you were looking for but did not know it existed. ;)

**EDIT**: ok, I was a bit vague, more information follows:

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilda_%28software%29):

> Tilda is a GTK+ terminal emulator. Its design was inspired from consoles in computer games such as Quake which slide down from the top of the screen when a key is pressed, typically the tilde, and slide back up when the key is pressed again.
>
> Running Tilda can be faster than launching a new terminal with a keyboard shortcut because the program is already loaded into memory; it can be useful to people who frequently find themselves opening and closing terminals for odd tasks.

`guake` is really the same thing, the only difference I noticed is that I couldn't make it open http links by ctrl+click which I found annoying

Answer (score 1):

My version  (=

Script to run/raise any app:

```
PID=$$
xdotool search --class $1 | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [ `xdotool windowactivate $line 2> /dev/stdout | grep -c fail` -eq 0 ]
    then
    kill $PID
    exit
  fi
done
## Launch the program if we reach here
$1 & disown
```

e.g.

```
sh ~/raise.sh chromium
```

You can grab newer and more functional version at https://github.com/010penetrator/dotfiles/blob/master/sh/raise.sh

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
wmctrl -xa 'gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal'
```

go to system settings - Keyborad, add a custom shortcut, and paste the wmctrl command there. It works.

where the gnome-terminal-* string is from

```
wmctrl -xl
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option: launch or switch. The script relies on wmctrl to check whether a window is already open. If it is, the script switches to an existing one, giving priority to an existing window on the current desktop. Otherwise, a new window is lauched. This script is [published by Vaughn Dickson](http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2008-April/005611.html).

```
#!/bin/sh

terminal_wm_class="gnome-terminal"
terminal_exec="gnome-terminal"

# no terminal started, so start one
if [ -z "`wmctrl -lx | grep gnome-terminal`" ]; then
    $terminal_exec &
else
    # search for existing terminals on current desktop
    current_desk=`wmctrl -d | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
    term_on_this_desk=`wmctrl -lx | grep "$current_desk[ ]*$terminal_wm_class" | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
    if [ -n "$term_on_this_desk" ]; then
        wmctrl -i -a $term_on_this_desk
    else
        # no terminals on current desktop, so just open the first one we find
        wmctrl -x -a $terminal_wm_class
    fi;
fi;
```

Place this script in the bin folder in your home folder and make it executable. Then under Keyboard Shortcuts (Settings - Keyboard), disable the existing hotkey for "Launch terminal" under the section "Launchers": click on it, then press Backspace to disable the current assignment. Then, in the section "Custom Shortcuts", create a new custom shortcut by clicking the + icon. Fill out the name of your script as the "command" and assign it the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut.