# Help with xdotool

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, conky, xdotool

I'm trying to make Conky work with Lubuntu using xdotool.

```
xdotool search --class "Pcmanfm" behave %2 focus windowraise $(xdotool search --class "Conky")
```

I get an error:

```
xdotool: Unknown command: 44040194
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xdotool search --class "Conky"` finds multiple windows, and results in multiple window IDs - the first makes sense at this place, but the second it is at a place where the first `xdotool` expects the next command.

You should change the search `xdotool search --class "Conky"` to match only one window.

If that is not possible, you could use `$(xdotool search --class "Conky" | head -n 1)` to choose just one of them, whithout knowing which,

or a solution like [xdotool: Unknown command: 21043361](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209784/xdotool-unknown-command-21043361)