# Permanent bind key for Terminal to drop-down

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm not using   <kbd>right CTRL</kbd>  .

Is it possible to bind key for terminal app to get in on top current workspace or hide? (show/hide window)

It doesn't necessarily have to be  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  key. It's about assigning a specific application to the key.

Working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking: DROP DOWN TERMINAL

Adds a terminal available from anywhere.

In Ubuntu Software I found 4 apps after typing "drop-down".

- Drop Down Terminal as Gnome extension
- Yakuake
- Tilda
- QTerminal

I chose Tilda, because I can configure copy and past shorcuts.

There is some old answer with the same problem: 

[Focus existing terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200929/focus-existing-terminal-with-ctrl-alt-t-shortcut)

[How to programmatically switch to a specific window in compiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000050/how-to-programmatically-switch-to-a-specific-window-in-compiz)

Answer (score 0):

By default, an hotkey is already defined in Ubuntu (at least my version, 18.10) to hide the current window: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. So press that key combination while your terminal is in the foreground, and it will disappear as a hidden (minimized) window. THis will work for any window.

Probably the same hotkey is set by default in Ubuntu 18.04 as well, but if not, set (or change) the hotkey in `Settings` - `Keyboard` under the "Windows" section.