# How do I map 'Ctrl + Alt + T' to bring up all existing terminals, rather than open a new terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to change the keyboard shortcut 'CTRL + ALT + T'. The behavior I'd like is to open all existing terminals in the current workspace, and open a new one if there aren't any.

I'm using several previous questions ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346169/shortcut-to-bring-all-open-terminals-to-the-front), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200929/focus-existing-terminal-with-ctrl-alt-t-shortcut)), which work to varying degrees, but I'm currently stuck on getting the keyboard shortcut to work.

Here's what I've done so far. I went to Settings > Keyboard shortcuts, removed the existing shortcut for launching terminal, and added a custom shortcut:

[Custom shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m239a.jpg)

Added an executable script to my bin named 'terminal':

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXKBx.jpg)

Now, when I type 'terminal' into an open terminal, the script runs. But when I press 'Ctrl + Alt + T' nothing happens.

Comment: Try using the full path to the script for the shortcut command, maybe it doesn't evaluate `~/.bin` directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks this works.

Comment: Great, let me put this as answer , might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the shortcut command, you should use an absolute path to the script. It probably doesn't search in `~/.bin` directory.

Use

```
~/.bin/terminal
```

or

```
/home/adam/.bin/terminal
```